# ESXi R200 Compact Flash boot

Tags: vmware-esx, installation

I have used the ESXi installer ISO to install VMware ESX to my Compact Flash device which is connected via SATA. However, the server doesn't seem to be able to boot from it.

The installation was successful any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have figured the issue out.

The idea that it was the boot order wasn't set correctly in the BIOS was close, but it was actually due to the fact *I was selecting the wrong hard disk* from the boot menu! :)

Comment: It seems only fair that you should post your solution here, in case anyone else encounters the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing it was the boot order wasn't set correctly in the BIOS.  That killed us once.  :-)

Comment: Scott Warren, close was actually due to the fact I was selecting the wrong hard disk from the boot menu. Total idiot! Thanks anyway guys!